# convert float to LPCTSTR conversion

Tags: c++

how to convert float to LPCTSTR.
here is my code :

```
wchar_t buffer[256];
wsprintfW(buffer, L"%f", chart_data[0].x[i]);
m_Grid.SetItemText(i+1, 1, buffer);
```

when i run this code i get f in buffer.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows API function `wsprintf` (which has a name confusingly similar to the C standard function `swprintf`) has no support for floating-point.  Notice that [in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647550(v=vs.85).aspx), `f` is not a valid type indicator, and so it falls into the behavior of "If a percent sign is followed by a character that has no meaning as a format field, the character is not formatted" causing a format string of `%f` to give you the result of just `f` which you observed.

An easy fix is to use your language's runtime library (e.g. `swprintf` or `std::to_string` or `boost::lexical_cast`) in order to handle floating-point values.

If you really want to avoid the language runtime (to avoid a dependency on any library not shipped with Windows, for example), then `VariantChangeType` supports additional conversions that `wsprintf` doesn't (floating-point values, currency, dates).  The function that `VariantChangeType` uses for the specific conversion you need (and which you can call directly for simplicity) is `VarBstrFromR8`, which differs in that it allocates the output buffer, which you'll need to free using `SysFreeString`.

```
#include <oleauto.h>

BSTR itemText;
VarBstrFromR8(chart_data[0].x[i], GetThreadLocale(), 0, &itemText);
m_Grid.SetItemText(i+1, 1, itemText);
SysFreeString(itemText);
```

Comment: Almost an answer, but the OP needs an `LPCTSTR`. They probably don't, but that's what they asked for...

Comment: @IInspectable: According to the title, yes, but according to the actual question, it's `wchar_t`, not `TCHAR`, that is wanted.  `wsprintfW` also is the wide name of the API.

Comment: I understand, and I don't think that the OP really needs a generic-text pointer. It's still something that is being asked for, and future visitors may be disappointed to find, that this answer doesn't address this. A note should be sufficient. Likewise, a note on why using a `BSTR` is safe in this case would be helpful to preempt future questions and confusion.